# waitForMessage ROS2 equivalent?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 there was the useful function ros::topic::waitForMessage(..). Is there an equivalent for ROS2 yet?

I have found the following question from a while ago: https://answers.ros.org/question/307370/ros2-whats-the-best-way-to-wait-for-a-new-message/

but maybe there is an easier solution available now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378693/waitformessage-ros2-equivalent?/) by [bvaningen](https://answers.ros.org/users/39746/bvaningen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2021-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: there is not. Looking at the latest rclcpp API, I can also confirm that there is no equivalent there https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html.

While I'm not entirely confident to say that it would never be added, I find it highly unlikely that it would be added - though your link suggests it may be possible through the C API so perhaps it will be exposed at the C++ level at some point. Please create a subscriber as you ordinarily would. It would not be terribly difficult to create an object that contains a subscriber, a callback, and a `getLatestMsg()` function to get the latest message to have a similar effect.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvaningen](https://answers.ros.org/users/39746/bvaningen/) on 2021-05-21**:
all right, thanks for the clarification!